# MVC 2.0 - different view based on URL with shared controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have 2 master pages.  One is intended to be shown in a normal standalone website.  The other is to be used in external sites as an Iframe.

I want to be able to show the normal page at http://example.com/home/index and the iframed version at http://example.com/framed/home/index

I want to have controls that will postback to one controller so I don't have to duplicate logic, so they must be available in both the normal and iframed versions.

My problem is that when I try and use areas, I just can't get them to work right with the default url.  Also, I have the added complication of structuremap.  When I try and hit /area/controller/action, I get

> The IControllerFactory
>   'MySite.Web.Code.IoC.StructureMapControllerFactory'
>   did not return a controller for the
>   name 'MyArea'.

Does anyone know how to make this kind of setup work?  Really all I'm doing is trying to show one set of views if it has /Framed/controller/action and another set if it does not have /framed.  I thought areas were the way to go, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of our controllers implement the same base class, and we use the following override to do what you're describing:

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
{
    if (masterName == null)
    {
        var options = PortalRequestManager.CurrentPortalRouteOptions;
        masterName = options.MvcMasterPath;
    }
    return base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
}
```

All of our AreaRegistrations use the following method to register their areas:

```
    public static void RegisterMvcAreaRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string url,
                                             object defaults)
    {
        context.MapRoute(name + "Portal",
                         "P/Channel/" + url,
                         defaults);
        context.MapRoute(name + "FramePortal",
                         "F/Channel/" + url,
                         defaults);
    }
```

And then the PortalRequestManager that you saw in the first code block parses the URL to see if it uses "/P" or "/F" to determine which MvcMasterPath to use.

We use Ninject's controller factory, which has no problem with this setup, so I can't really speak to your problems with StructureMap.

Comment: My problem is that the /P and /F in your case are treated like controllers, no matter how I do my routing, and then null is passed into my controller factory for controllerType.

Comment: I wonder if you have a routing defined somewhere that's overriding the other routes? For example, if your Global.asax.cs file maps a route to `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, then this would conflict with other routes that begin with something other than controller. In our case, *all* of our routes begin with "F" or "P", so there is no conflict. Search your code for references to `MapRoute` and make sure there are no interfering routes being registered.

Comment: I did something similar to get it work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943556/mvc-2-0-structuremap-areas-and-duplicate-controller-names